# make the server wait the [FIN + ACK] from the client before closing the socket

Tags: php, sockets, networking, tcp

I have the following php script (tcp server)

```
<?php

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

// Bind the socket to an address/port
socket_bind($sock, "0.0.0.0", 14010) or die('Could not bind to address');
$i=0;
for(;;) {
    // Start listening for connections
    socket_listen($sock);

    /* Accept incoming requests and handle them as child processes */
    $client = socket_accept($sock);

    // Read the input from the client &#8211; 1024 bytes
    $in = socket_read($client, 41984);

    socket_write($client, $in);

    //socket_close($client);
}

// Close the master sockets

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

How I can make the server wait the [FIN + ACK] from the client before closing the socket?

Comment: You only want to `listen` once (outside the loop) and then `accept` multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead of calling `close`, do a `recv` on socket (not sure of php construct). `recv` system call returns 0 on peer closure. If this is the case you can then `close` on server side.